# How to call Jasper Report in java (Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.1 )

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have successfully installed and created report using Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.1 (not iReport Designer) on windows 10. 

Since Jaspersoft Studio generate only one .jrxml file(not like iReport) i can't think where to put it and how to call it through java class...

Could anyone explain how to call it from java class?, that would be great help for me and other newbies.

Yes, of course i went through several example that can be found with google search. but all of them are outdated. I'll post links to those posts below.

[Link -1](http://www.sliitrevolution.yolasite.com/resources/Calling_iReports_from_a_Java_programEN.pdf) 
[Link -2](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/524537/example-java-program-call-jasper-report)

Comment: [Fill JasperReport Template using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jasper-reports/3958/fill-report/13819/fill-jasperreport-template-using-java#t=201611101852582626471) & [JasperReports - Sample Reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html)

Comment: There are tons samples on SO and other sites

Comment: what are the libraries need to be copied to java project?